# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS + Xen : Ubuntu runs as dom0?

Tags: xen, ubuntu-12.04

Considering the 'news' that XCP is [now officially supported in Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.xen.org/news/2012/05_xcp_in_ubuntu_server_12_04_LTS.html), how is it exactly supported? Does Ubuntu 12.04 now run 'officially' in dom0? Or does it run as a VM?

Also, if running Ubuntu in dom0, what is the recommended pattern for a minimal footprint install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, Ubuntu 12.04 now runs as a dom0 OS. I would not call it 'official support' because the setup isn't seamless by any stretch.

So as a side note to the original question, the Ubuntu+Xen setup was overly complicated (fragmented toolchains, spotty documentation, no well advertised FOSS GUI management tools). So we are now running off Hyper-V, which is also free and very straight forward to setup. Considering we had 0 experience in both, Hyper-V was ridiculously productive for us allowing us to focus on business rather than IT.